# How to extract subimages from an image?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

What are the ways to count and extract all subimages given a master image?

#### Sample 1

Input:

[image]

Output should be 8 subgraphs.

#### Sample 2

Input:

[image]

Output should have 6 subgraphs.

Note: These image samples are taken from internet. Images can be of random dimensions.

Is there a way to draw lines of separation in these image and then split based on those details ?

e.g :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, there'll be a general solution to extract all single figures properly from arbitrary tables of figures (as shown in the two examples) – at least using some kind of "simple" image-processing techniques.

For "perfect" tables with constant grid layout and constant colour space between single figures (as shown in the two examples), the following approach might be an idea:

1. Calculate the mean standard deviation in `x` and `y` direction, and threshold using some custom parameter. The mean standard deviation within the constant colour spaces should be near zero. A custom parameter will be needed here, since there'll be artifacts, e.g. from JPG compression, which effects might be more or less severe.
2. Do some binary closing on the mean standard deviations using custom parameters. There might be small constant colour spaces around captions or similar, cf. the second example. Again, custom parameters will be needed here, too.
3. From the resulting binary "signal", we can extract the start and stop positions for each subimage, thus the subimage itself by slicing from the original image. Attention: That works only, if the tables show a constant grid layout!

That'd be some code for the described approach:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import binary_closing


def extract_from_table(image, std_thr, kernel_x, kernel_y):

    # Threshold on mean standard deviation in x and y direction
    std_x = np.mean(np.std(image, axis=1), axis=1) > std_thr
    std_y = np.mean(np.std(image, axis=0), axis=1) > std_thr

    # Binary closing to close small whitespaces, e.g. around captions
    std_xx = binary_closing(std_x, np.ones(kernel_x))
    std_yy = binary_closing(std_y, np.ones(kernel_y))

    # Find start and stop positions of each subimage
    start_y = np.where(np.diff(np.int8(std_xx)) == 1)[0]
    stop_y = np.where(np.diff(np.int8(std_xx)) == -1)[0]
    start_x = np.where(np.diff(np.int8(std_yy)) == 1)[0]
    stop_x = np.where(np.diff(np.int8(std_yy)) == -1)[0]

    # Extract subimages
    return [image[y1:y2, x1:x2, :]
            for y1, y2 in zip(start_y, stop_y)
            for x1, x2 in zip(start_x, stop_x)]


for file in (['image1.jpg', 'image2.png']):
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    subimages = extract_from_table(img, 5, 21, 11)
    print('{} subimages found.'.format(len(subimages)))
    for i in subimages:
        cv2.imshow('subimage', i)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The `print` output is:

```
8 subimages found.
6 subimages found.
```

Also, each subimage is shown for visualization purposes.

For both images, the same parameters were suitable, but that's just some coincidence here!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
OpenCV:        4.5.1
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only extract the sub-images using simple array slicing technique. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. But if one knows the table columns and rows, I think you can extract the sub-images.

````
image = cv2.imread('table.jpg')
p = 2 #number of rows
q = 4 #number of columns

width, height, channels = image.shape

width_patch = width//p
height_patch = height//q
x=0
for i in range(0, width - width_patch, width_patch):
    for j in range(0, height - height_patch, height_patch):
        crop = image[i:i+width_patch, j:j+height_patch]
        cv2.imwrite("image_{0}.jpg".format(x),crop)
        x+=1
        # cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
        # cv2.waitKey(0)```
````